# Rollback Or Hide Error Prone App's Update/Release From Google Play Console/Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, app-distribution

After unpublishing the Error Prone App's Update/Release from Google Play Console, but It still shows “Update” for all the existing users that have already installed the same App.

Is there any way to hide/remove the Update of the current buggy app's update/release from the Google Play Store OR restrict the users from updating the App? As It takes time to remove the bug and upload the correct/stable release.